# angularjs rest get method not working with .appcache enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, html5-appcache

I am working with an angular app which is consuming rest services, and I need to have an `.appcache` file to work offline.

When I have this header into the UI:

```
<html lang=""  ng-app="labsisApp">
```

And I have this code  in the controller:

```
   $http.get('http://localhost:2700/users')
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.users = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.onLine = false;
    });
```

Is works!, but when appcache is enable:

```
<html lang="" manifest="labsis.appcache" ng-app="labsisApp">
```

Get request doesnt work, in spite of having this appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
index.html
styles/main.css
scripts/application.js
scripts/angular.min.js
scripts/angular-route.min.js
scripts/lodash.min.js
scripts/restangular.min.js
scripts/main.js
```

All the important files are into the appcachefile.
This problem just appears when I enable the appcache, and a problem with angular is thowed. POST method works, but GET method doesnt work.

Comment: `Get request doesnt work`. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The url `/users` is not listed in your cache manifest. With a cache manifest file, the client will never go to the server to request data. It will always look in the cache. If it can't find it, it will fail.

There are (at least) two ways to solve this. One is to add a `NETWORK` section to the cache manifest:

```
NETWORK:
/users
```

Which will allow the client to request that url when online, but will fail if it is requested offline. With this solution, anytime you do a request for a resource listed in you `NETWORK` section you must check to see if you are online or offline first, and do something different if you are offline (load the data from localStorage instead, for example).

Another solution is to add `/users` to your `CACHE:` section.